# Entity Framework Core - Error when trying to Add Migration after creating Model from existing database

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have .NET Core Project with Entity Framework Core. I created a model from an existing database using the following command

Scaffold-DbContext "Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=DBName;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models

The Model was generated and I tried to add migration but the migration that is generated is actually trying to create anew the already existing tables in the database. So when I try to run Update-Database I naturally run into the following error

> Applying migration '20200912095755_SetMaxLengthToBookTitle'. Failed
> executing DbCommand (20ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text',
> CommandTimeout='30'] CREATE TABLE [Authors] (
> [Id] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
> [Name] nvarchar(max) NULL,
> CONSTRAINT [PK_Authors] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]) ); Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): There is already
> an object named 'Authors' in the database.    at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
> Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
> stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
> SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
> BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
> stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)

What is the reason for that and what is the correct way to update database after creating the model from an already existing database in EF Core?

Comment: It's either code first (with migrations) or DB first (with code generated from tables), you have to pick one

Comment: Yes, but with Entity Framework it was possible to do code first with an existing DB. Is this not possible with Entity Framework Core?

Comment: Roll-back your model change so it is as originally scaffolded. Delete all of your migrations, then create a fresh initial migration e.g. dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate. Then make your model change, and create a second migration. Remove the first migration, and see if EF will apply the second migration. May take some experimenting.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the answer that I found for myself is that I have to add an Initial migration and delete everything in it to make an empty migration. From then on I can proceed by using the code first approach as with the option 'Code first from database' that was available in EF 6.